# Fine tuning of std::unordered_set or map for user-defined types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

`std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` allow's to use custom types with corresponding custom `hash` and `equal` functions. The asymptotic complexity of adding new elements operation depends on complexity of this pair of functions. I think there possible some kind of balancing. But can't infer how to perform it.

What to do, if `equal` return `false` 100 times more often then `true`? There are `max_load_factor` and `reserve` member-functions. How to use them for diverse scenarios?

[For example](https://github.com/tomilov/quickhull/blob/ae1f5da58cd39228e970605f205a3a7c63ac965e/include/quickhull.hpp#L549), `hash` function is *O(1)* and very cheap. But `equal` function is 100-1000 times longer to calculate for some input (`rbox D10 30 t`).